# possible to have mutiple senders in a single SMTP email

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

we have those conditions:

- we use Java API to send SMTP emails
- currently all system emails are send from a sysAdmin@xx.com
- the user who triggered the email, his email address get added into the cc field

I wander is it possible to move the user email address to the sender filed, so customers
would receive a single email send fromo both sysAdmin and the user?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very well defined, but it sounds to me like you should put the user in `From:` and add `Sender: sysAdmin@xx.com`.

If your customers use a Microsoft client, it will display something silly like "From sysAdmin@xx.com on behalf of user@example.com" but then I suppose if they use Microsoft clients, you can't really win.